# How to use servlet asyncIO with async processing?

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, nio

I couldn't find any example on how to use servlet aysnc IO with async processing.
Specifically, I want to know if reader and writer listerners are to be attached to servlet input and output streams BEFORE or AFTER we submit the async context to a custom threadpool.

If we take [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html) as an example, at which part of the code we should say `request.getInputStream().setReadListener()` ? You can see this method use example [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/non_blocking_i_o_using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you submit the context to a thread pool first, the first (and only?) thing the other thread will do is to attach the `ReadListener`.
- If you attach the `ReadListener` in the servlet I don't see what the custom thread pool will do, unless there is something to be done before the request body is read. The `ReadListener` will be called by a container thread.

So it comes down to if there is some work that needs to be done before starting to read the request body.

- If you can read the whole request into memory, you can submit the request to a thread pool once the whole request is read.
- If not, you can submit chunks of the request to a thread pool, if this is necessary.